# Finding cell with specific value and return position

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I want to code a function which finds a date, which is stored in a variable, and returns its address.

This is what I have got so far

```
Dim ran As Range
Dim dat As Date
dat = "01.05.2009  15:42:00"

Set ran = Cells.Find(What:=dat, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If ran Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("no result")
    Else
    MsgBox (ran.Address)

End If
```

When I run this snippet, it always returns "no result". However when I do not use variables and put it like this

```
Dim ran As Range
Dim dat As Date

Set ran = Cells.Find(What:="01.05.2009  15:42:00", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If ran Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("no result")
    Else
    MsgBox (ran.Address)

End If
```

it returns the address of the cell as expected.

Since I want to use this code snippet later in a larger project, I need this to work with a variable such that it can be used in a loop with a series of different searches.

I would be very grateful if somebody can tell me where I am going wrong, or knows an better approach to this.

Comment: Do you have an `On Error Resume Next` hiding out somewhere? `dat = "01.05.2009  15:42:00"` will throw a type mismatch error, because that is not a valid date representation. Note - is your underlying data *text-that-looks-like-dates*?

Comment: the intended cells are indeed formatted as dates (DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm)
Strangely I am not getting an error on `dat = "01.05.2009 15:42:00"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are displaying dates in your worksheet as something like Custom "mm.dd.yy HH:MM:SS" Find is a little finicky about looking for dates and works most predictably when you search for a date string that matches your display format.

I think your code will work if you declare dat as String, or if you are working with a Date variable (instead of hard coding the value, as in your example), use

```
What:=Format(dat, "mm.dd.yy HH:MM:SS")
```

Nonetheless @BigBen is correct that the code you have posted should raise an error on

```
dat = "01.05.2009  15:42:00"
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Declaring dat as String did work for me. Interestingly, my original Code worked without problems on my secondary pc. Even more odd: on that pc the code does NOT work when dat is declared as String. how can that be?